# Is there a method to update all of my textmate bundles at once from the git repository?

Tags: git, textmate, bundle

I am trying to update all of my Textmate bundles to the most current version.  Is there a way to do this without doing each bundle individually? If not how do I update an individual bundle? I don't know how to use svn so I would prefer to use the git repository.

Thanks for helping a noob! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the "Get Bundles" (with an "s" not "Get Bundle"--that's a different Bundle) Bundle

To install:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
svn co http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Review/Bundles/GetBundles.tmbundle/
```

(Alternatively, you can grab the "Get Bundles" Bundle from git.)

Once installed, you probably need to re-start TextMate.

Next, click "Bundles" in the Menu Bar, then click "Get Bundles" which will bring up a small sub-menu;

Click "Get Bundles" in that sub-menu.

This will bring up the Get Bundles GUI. In the upper left-hand corner are four buttons that refer to four different repositories ("Official", "Review", "3rd Party", and "All").

Click the right-most button "All"

In the bottom left-hand cornder of the GUI, click the "gear menu" which will bring up a menu, click "Install all Updates" from that menu (also accessible with cmd-U).

Comment: I don't think I have subversion.  Can I do this with git?

Comment: yes--"Get Bundles" is also on git (updated my answer in light of your comment).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go the Get Bundles route (and there's no reason not to per se, but I thought I'd provide an alternative), here's a script I use to manage my bundles:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

Dir.glob('*.tmbundle') do |bundle|
    bundle =~ /^(.*)\.tmbundle$/
    puts "=> Updating #{$1}:"
    if File.exists? "#{bundle}/.svn"
        system %Q/cd "#{bundle}" && svn update/
    elsif File.exists? "#{bundle}/.git"
        system %Q/cd "#{bundle}" && git pull/
    else
        $stderr.puts 'Unknown version control system, skipping'
    end
end
```

I threw this in `/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles`. Whenever I want to update all my bundles, I navigate there and run it. It loops through each bundle and updates via the appropriate version control mechanism (Subversion or Git).

Answer (score 0):

You have various scripts out there to help deal with the recursive aspect of submodules:

- [batch script](http://imyousuf-tech.blogs.smartitengineering.com/2008/01/propagating-git-commands-to-its.html)
- [perl script for recursive update](http://gaarai.com/2009/09/16/recursively-updating-git-submodules/)
- [shell script](http://muckandbrass.com/web/display/~cemerick/2009/09/25/Working+with+git+submodules+recursively)
- [git clone script with submodules](http://www.golden-gryphon.com/blog/manoj/miscellaneous/clone_repo.html)

Plus the [`git submodules` commands](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) have now a recursive option attached to them.