# TextMate - must-have Bundles and Plugins for web dev

Tags: macos, text-editor, textmate

Just curious what experienced Textmate users can't live without in the program. I just ran the trial and bought the program so I'm trying to get a sense of how others might setup their development environment for web development.

Also, based on the fact that I just bought the program, I am going to guess that TM2 will come out next week. Yes, that's right, next week. Unfortunately, because of my luck, it will not be a free upgrade...upgrades will cost more.

Comment: Sorry, deleted and reposted as Community Wiki as per someone's suggestion.

Comment: At least it's only cheap. I am on the trail version at the moment and I've got the Drupal bundle installed. I'm liking it a lot so far! http://github.com/psynaptic/php-drupal.tmbundle

Comment: just couple of very minor edits to your Q (just Title & Tags), only substantive one is i added the word "Bundle" because those are far more important than Plug-ins (Bundles outnumber Plug-ins probably 100 to 1)--thought that's what you mean anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Well if anyone is new to TextMate, you need to install the "**Get Bundles**" Bundle--a GUI to the TextMate SVN and git Bundle repositories. More detail on installing the 'Get Bundles' Bundle in an answer to a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483389/is-there-a-method-to-update-all-of-my-textmate-bundles-at-once-from-the-git-repos/2483933#2483933) on SO.

I think this is the easiest way to not only view all available Bundles but also to update them on your own rig.

As of five minutes ago, Get Bundles counts **793 total TM Bundles** available either in the Official TM SVN Repository or on the TM git Repository.

Once you have that, you can "go shopping"--so for instance if you're a web developer then you can quickly see that there are (at least):

- six different Bundles for CSS
  (including the official TM CSS Bundle
  that comes pre-installed)
- six Bundles for Django
- six Bundles for HTML, etc.

Of course, the Web Dev framework with the largest TM user base is RoR; i quickly counted a dozen different RoR Bundles though i am sure there are more.

I use several TM Plug-ins:

- MissingDrawer
- SVNMate
- TmCodeBRowser
- TMQuickLook
- WebMate

Answer (score 1):

I use [E](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) a pc version of textmate and I'd be lost without html [zen-coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) and they have versions for textmate.  Highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of web development do you do? I have noted, on a previous SO thread, [some good bundles for Ruby on Rails development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391247/textmate-tips-for-rails-development/2391544#2391544).

Comment: Right now I'm just using PHP for server-side.  I'm looking for a good first PHP framework as well...Kohana is looking nice.